# input and div displacing inline items

Tags: html, css

For some reason, when using div and input combined, the next `inline` item is displaced. See example below.

```css
    div.inline-flex {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <header>Object control:</header>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            Snap to grid size: 
            <div style="font-size: 12px;">(default: 50)</div>
            <input 
                type="number" 
                value="50" 
                v-model="gridSize" 
                style="width: 50px;"
            /> 
            <button 
                :class="{active: store.state.DrawMap.shouldSnap}" 
                @click="store.commit('drawmap_toggle_snap')"
            >
                Snap
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-flex" style="flex-direction: column">
            <button 
   
                @click="remove_object"
            >   
                Remove
            </button>
       
        </div>
</div>
```

**What it should look like**

The remove button should be next to the `Snap to grid size` line.

```css
div.inline-flex {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <header>Object control:</header>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            Snap to grid size:  
            <button 
                :class="{active: store.state.DrawMap.shouldSnap}" 
                @click="store.commit('drawmap_toggle_snap')"
            >
                Snap
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-flex" style="flex-direction: column">
            <button 
   
                @click="remove_object"
            >   
                Remove
            </button>
       
        </div>
</div>

input and div were removed
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get your desired output, but i think is this.

```css
div.inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>Object control:</header>
  <div style="display: inline-block; float:left;">
    Snap to grid size:
    <div style="font-size: 12px;">(default: 50)</div>
    <input type="number" value="50" v-model="gridSize" style="width: 50px;" />
    <button :class="{active: store.state.DrawMap.shouldSnap}" @click="store.commit('drawmap_toggle_snap')">
                Snap
            </button>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="inline-flex" style="flex-direction: column;">
      <button @click="remove_object">   
                Remove
            </button>

    </div>
```

Comment: Currently looks like what I want, I'll take a look at it closer and mark as appropriate.

Comment: No, the answer isn't quite right, it looks like it was just shoe horned to make it work. I need it as a separate block because there's more content in it.

Comment: Oh, ok.. gotcha, let me think

Comment: I'm really looking for an explanation. I've solved it using flexbox but I'm just wondering why it's being displaced like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are Setting the inline to "(default: 50)" rather than "Snap to Grid". If you move the declaration of "(default: 50)" to the end, then the buttons will be displayed inline to "Snap to Grid".

```css
    div.inline-flex {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <header>Object control:</header>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            Snap to grid size: 
            <input 
                type="number" 
                value="50" 
                v-model="gridSize" 
                style="width: 50px;"
            /> 
            <button 
                :class="{active: store.state.DrawMap.shouldSnap}" 
                @click="store.commit('drawmap_toggle_snap')"
            >
                Snap
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-flex" style="flex-direction: column">
            <button 
   
                @click="remove_object"
            >   
                Remove
            </button>
       
        </div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px;">(default: 50)</div>
</div>
```

---update----

```css
    div.inline-flex {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <header>Object control:</header>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            Snap to grid size: 
            <div class="inline-flex" style="flex-direction: column">
            <button 
   
                @click="remove_object"
            >   
                Remove
            </button>
       
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 12px;">(default: 50)</div>
            <input 
                type="number" 
                value="50" 
                v-model="gridSize" 
                style="width: 50px;"
            /> 
            <button 
                :class="{active: store.state.DrawMap.shouldSnap}" 
                @click="store.commit('drawmap_toggle_snap')"
            >
                Snap
            </button>
        </div>
        
      
</div>
```

Comment: you've altered my layout altogether

Comment: I assumed you wanted everything in one line instead of just the remove button.  Have a look at the 2nd Snippet.

Comment: The reason why my `remove` button is in another container is because there's a lot more items in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `vertical-align:top` to quick fix it.

```
  div.inline-flex {
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```